# How to get a list of objects in jQuery from s:hidden tag in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, struts2

What's the best way to send a list of objects from a **Struts 2** action  to JavaScript?

I'm trying to send data this way but it just doesn't work

```
Action >>> JSP : <s:hidden>  >>> Javascript

<s:hidden id="listObj" value="%{objects}" />
```

This line get me object names array as a string:

```
$('#listObj').val()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert a list of objects to JSON like this

```
String objectsJson = new Gson().toJson(objects);
```

You should use getters to access a variable in jsp.

Now, you need to parse this text via javascript. You can use `JSON.parse('${objectsJson}')` in JSP to get a javascript object or 
if the object is stored in hidden field

```
var objects = JSON.parse($('#listObj').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the list of `objects` to populate your js array, using JSTL:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<script>
    var list = [];
    <c:forEach items="${objects}" var="o">
        list.push("${o}")
    </c:forEach>
</script>
```

Or same stuff with old-school scriplets..

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: +1 for the iteration, -1 for the old-school scriptlets. Change scriptlets with OGNL way for a positive net :)